# I am using Tanstack table in ReactJS (useReactTable), I want to first set column filters then apply them instead of applying one by one

Tags: reactjs, rerender, tanstack

I have multiple column filters. and I am applying filters using

```
<TABLE_INSTANCE>.getColumn("team").setFilterValue(team)  
<TABLE_INSTANCE>.getColumn("user").setFilterValue(team)
```

But it will re-render the table 2 times. I want to render the table one time only like just set `filterValues` first then apply the filters

I want function/API which will first apply the filtervalue then apply the filters on table so that I avoid unwanted re-renders

Answer (score 0):

use can try this approach this works for me. I make an example from my code.

```
const MyTableComponent = () => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
    setFilter, // This is the function we'll use
  } = useTable(
    {
      // Your table options here
    },
    useFilters // Be sure to apply the useFilters hook
  );

  const applyFilters = () => {
    // Set filter values for multiple columns
    setFilter("team", "Team A");
    setFilter("user", "User B");

    // This will trigger the filtering in a single render
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={applyFilters}>Apply Filters</button>
      <table {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map(row => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>;
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```